# Segmentation fault in C while trying to declare an array of strings.

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, segmentation-fault

"fruits.txt" is a text file that starts with a number, say n,  followed by the names of n fruits.I want to store those n names into an array of strings, but while trying to declare that array, I am getting "Segmentation fault(core dumped) error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int count;
    fp = fopen("fruits.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file!!");
        exit(0);
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &count);
    printf("%d\n", count);
    char *fruits[count]; // This line is giving Segmentation fault.
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this issue? Which platform are you on?

Comment: If you're on MSVC which doesn't support variable length array, then `char *fruits[count];` would give you an error.

Comment: The `count` is too large?

Comment: @ssjam: I don't think it is MSVC, because "segmentation fault" is called "access violation" on Windows. But that is certainly not the only compiler that doesn't implement it. AFAIK, in C++11 and above, it is optional. But it obviously compiles, otherwise it could not cause a segfault.

Comment: It won't compile in MSVC, so it can't give a runtime error.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I just wanted to add that to my comment. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis : I doubted that too.. That just mentioned `error` in the comment. and IIRC the program won't compile

Comment: @ssjam: I'm on Linux(Ubuntu).

Comment: Following up on @BLUEPIXY's comment, how large is `count`?  On most common C implementations, variable-length arrays are allocated on the stack, which is of limited size, say a few megabytes.  So if `count` is more than a million or so, I would expect this to overflow the stack (hey, you came to the right site!).  Stack overflow usually results in a segfault rather than graceful failure.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I tried setting count to 8 & 1000000, both of the times I got the same error.

Comment: @Romy Is this the actual code?

Comment: Can you post the exact contents of `fruits.txt`?  Also, you ought to check the return value of `fscanf`; if it fails, `count` may be left containing garbage.

Comment: @Romy 
You do not have things like `fscanf(fp, "%s", fruits[i])` ?

Comment: @Romy , I added test code with a `for` loop which reads each fruit name into a buffer, `malloc`s `fruits[i]`, `strcpy(fruits[i],buffer)` and verifies the result. Can't reproduce the problem. compiler: `clang`.

Comment: What does this line `printf("%d\n", count);` print?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: sorry, actual code means? I didn't proceeded further as I was getting error.

Comment: Perhaps segment fault does not occur If you set the count to 8 in the post code .

Comment: @NateEldredge: Here are the contents of 'fruits.txt' 
8
Apple
Mango
Orange
Banana
Papaya
Mango
Fig
Grape
_______
I am printing 'count' for verifying its value after 'fsacnf', is it okay?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: It's occurring, don't know why. :/

Comment: @alk: it is printing the value of count correctly.

Comment: Did you (save and ) re-compile (or re-build)?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Yes, I did.

Comment: It does not reproduce.

Comment: There is no difference was posted code and the code you have?

Comment: I just ran your code, It worked well. I use the gcc v4.4.7.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY There is no difference.
I tried running exactly the same code on a different machine(Cent OS) & it is working fine, but in my machine(in which I used persistent Ubuntu) it's not working.Any ideas why is it happening?

Comment: I think that You're misunderstanding something. or It is broken something (OS, IDE, compiler , etc.) that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you wish to provide storage (memory) to hold the fruit names as you read them, you have 2 options (2) use the little know `'m'` field modifier (it was `'a'` on older implementations so if you are on windoze, read the documentation to make a determination (or just try both and see which one works).

The immediate issue with your code was the fact that the `fopen` was called with the `"w"` file mode. That will only work if the `fruits.txt` *already exhisted* as the `"w"` mode will NOT create a file if it doesn't exist. The proper *mode* is `"w+"` (or `"a"` or `"a+"`, either of which will also create a non-existing file). Simply changing your *mode* to `"w+"` will allow the fruit info to be written to a newly created `fruits.txt`.

The issue regarding use of a VLA (variable length array) on some MS compilers may present issues. You will just have to look at your version and the changelogs or documentation (or just try and read the error or warnings. Worse case, you can use a *pointer-to-pointer-to-type*, or a static array of sufficient size. Given your use of `fscanf` that approach is continued below. Specifically though:

```
    char *fruits[count]; /* here you delare an array of pointers to type char   */
                        /* utilizing a variable length array. some MS compiler */
                        /* version do not handle VLA's, VS13/VS15 should be ok */

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)       /* read & allocate for each array element */
        if (fscanf (fp, " %ms", &fruits[i]) != 1) {    /* m allocates, a for ms */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: read/allocation for fruits[%d] failed.\n", i);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
```

(Note the format string used above `" %ms"` which has the caveat that the pointer to accept the allocation block must be a *pointer-to-pointer* to `char *` -- which is the *address of* the pointer to allocate/file, e.g. `&fruits[i]`)

The remainder of the code should be very familiar, except now all input and other critical points in the code have been *validated* by checking the `return` provided by whatever function to insure no error condition existed up to that point and that none was caused by the operation in question. That is the only way you can have confidence in the operation of your code. Get in the habit.

Putting that together, you could come up with the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    int count, i;
    FILE *fp;

    if (!(fp = fopen ("fruits.txt", "w+"))) {  /* "w+" required to create file */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed 'fruits.txt'.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fputs ("4 Apple Banana mango berry", fp); /* write string to fruits.txt */
    fclose(fp);

    if (!(fp = fopen ("fruits.txt", "r"))) { /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed 'fruits.txt'.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fscanf (fp, " %d", &count) != 1) {  /* read all fruir from fruits.txt */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: in read of value from 'fruits.txt'.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf ("\n Quantity read from 'fruits.txt' is '%d'.\n\n", count);

    char *fruits[count]; /* here you delare an array of pointers to type char   */
                        /* utilizing a variable length array. some MS compiler */
                        /* version do not handle VLA's, VS13/VS15 should be ok */

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)       /* read & allocate for each array element */
        if (fscanf (fp, " %ms", &fruits[i]) != 1) {    /* m allocates, a for ms */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: read/allocation for fruits[%d] failed.\n", i);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    fclose(fp);  /* close file for the last time */

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) /* output array */
        printf (" fruit[%d] : %s\n", i, fruits[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) /* free allocated memory */
        free (fruits[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

A basic compile string for the code (in `abc.c`) and the executable placed in `bin/abc` could would be:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/abc abc.c -std=gnu11
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/abc

 Quantity read from 'fruits.txt' is '4'.

 fruit[0] : Apple
 fruit[1] : Banana
 fruit[2] : mango
 fruit[3] : berry
```

In any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory, attempted to read or base a jump on an unintitialized value and finally to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated. For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/abc
==30980== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30980== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30980== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30980== Command: ./bin/abc
==30980==

 Quantity read from 'fruits.txt' is '4'.

 fruit[0] : Apple
 fruit[1] : Banana
 fruit[2] : mango
 fruit[3] : berry
==30980==
==30980== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30980==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30980==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 1,561 bytes allocated
==30980==
==30980== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==30980==
==30980== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30980== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Always confirm *All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible* and equally important *ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts*. (although note: some OS's do not provide adequate memeory exclusion files (*the file that excludes system and OS memory from being reported as in use*) which will cause `valgrind` to report that some memory has not yet been freed (despite the fact you have done your job and freed al blocks you allocoted and under your control.

That's a lot to take in for a simple problem, and we didn't even talk about the preferred manner of reading the file would have been to read and entire line at a time with `fgets` or POSIX `getline` and then to either *parse* the individual fruits from the line read, or to *tokenize* the line with  `strtok`. Take the time to digest the cocde and answer for yourself the two compiler questions you must look up (1) support of VLA's for `fruits[count]` and (2) whether `m` or `a` is use by your compiler to allocate.

Answer (score 0):

When using `fscanf`, you must always check the return value. Only if the function returns a successful value (read the `fscanf` documentation for that), the program should continue.

Comment: "*successful value*" is an "interesting" phrase ... ;-)

Comment: I think he meant that to indicate that the *match count* returned has a one-to-one correlation to the *conversion specifiers*  present in the *format string*. `:p`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried below code and found working. 
The difference here is first i've created the file and filled the content in it.

If i don't fill contents in file then i gets segmentation fault (not on all compilers).
So it seems in your case the fscanf() is reading some junk and returning some big junk number.
As others also suggested, please check what fscanf returns. if it returns-1, means nothing is found in your file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int count;
    int i;

    fp = fopen ("fruits.txt", "w");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file!!");
        exit(0);
    }
    fputs("4 Apple Banana mango berry", fp);
    fclose(fp);*/

    fp = fopen("fruits.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file!!");
        exit(0);
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &count);
    printf("%d\n", count);

    fclose(fp);
    char *fruits[count]; // This line is giving Segmentation fault.

    return 0;
}
```

This prints 4 with no error/fault.